# Android Layout: Hide toolbar if scroll in FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, toolbar

I have a toolbar I would like to hide if the user scrolls down.
I found a solution where the view to be scrolled is a RecyclerView or a NestedScrollView.
In my case, I have a `FragmentContainerView` next to my toolbar.
 The FragmentContainerView hosts different fragments eg a WebView.
I tried different things like nesting the FragmentContainerView inside a NestedScrollView (Not displayed at all anymore).
This is my simplified layout file:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.abc.myApp.features.main.MainActivity">

  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Has anyone any idea that I could try out?

Comment: The `NestedScrollView` should be the root view of the guest fragment in the `FragmentContainerView`

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution using a third-party library 
As described, I inflated a `WebView` into the FragmentContainerView.
As Zain said, I need a NestedScrollView (wrapped around the WebView).
In my final solution, I replaced the WebView with the `NestedScrollWebView` from Telefonica:
https://github.com/Telefonica/android-nested-scroll-webview